# Show equation components one by one without changing their original location in the general equation

Tags: equations

I just wonder if there is a way to show equation components one by one without changing their original location in the general equation in Latex. In case it is not clear what I meant, I am attaching a simple example that hopefully shows what I am trying to do. So when I move between pages, the location of $m cosy$ will not change.

[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Important: Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/.

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
      \sin x + m \cdot \cos y + t \tan x = 1
      \label{eq:NiceEquation}
\end{equation}

I need to show the equation, \eqref{eq:NiceEquation}, in the following order.

\begin{align}
     &+ m \cdot \cos y\\
     &+ m \cdot \cos y + z \tan x = 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]